# convert LaTex citations back to MMD citations

Tags: biblatex, pandoc, markdown, pandoc-citeproc, scrivener

I wrote my dissertation in Scrivener in MMD. As I was putting in the final edits, I exported to LaTex and used biblatex-chicago for my citations. It worked great. However, I made lots of edits directly in that LaTex file.

Now that I'm ready to start book revisions, I'd like to import that final LaTex file back into Scrivener in MMD format using pandoc. I've been able to convert the latex file and its citations back into RTF, but they aren't formatted in the same way as they were in the original scrivener file.

Here's the line I'm running: pandoc --bibliography=bibliography.bib -o test11.rtf print-mmd.tex

I've also tried: 
pandoc --bibliography=bibliography.bib -o test11.md print-mmd.tex

Originally in Scrivener (MMD), an citation would look like this: [1172ff.][#hueber_dreyfache_1686;]

Then after export into LaTex it looked like this: \footnote{ \citet[1172ff.]{hueber_dreyfache_1686}.}

And now after running pandoc, the citation looks like this: @hueber_dreyfache_1686 [1173–4]

Is there any way to run pandoc on my Latex file and get my citations back to their original format in brackets? [page #][citekey]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This seems to be a pandoc or Scrivener (Scrivener probably should not turn that citation into `\footnote{\citet[1172ff]{foo}}`, I'd go for `\footcite[1172\psqq]{foo}` although they are not exactly the same) issue and not a `biblatex`- or LaTeX-related problem. You may have more luck asking this on the pandoc mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss. In general non-LaTeX-related pandoc questions are off-topic here, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6573/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6043/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7371/35864

Comment: Since `@hueber_dreyfache_1686 [1173–4]` is [valid syntax for in-text citations in pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations) **and** scrivener supports pandoc, you could just keep on using pandoc as markdown engine in scrivener instead of mmd. Chapter 21 of the [user manual](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/learn-and-support/user-guides) is called "Using
MultiMarkdown and Pandoc" and describes in detail how to do so.